# Trying to upsert mongodb subdocument array with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a straightforward mongo collection with an array of subdocuments. I'm trying to do the oft asked "upsert a subdocument in an array". I have read all questions on this topic, but can't seem to get it to work.

Data structure for game_managers:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("555cf465715ff974fb09221f"),
    "game_id" : "123456789",
    "players" : [ 
        {
            "request_email" : "thebigcheese@foobar.com",
            "request_notes" : "I love mongo!",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("551eb55f555b404d68b88063")
        },
        {
            "request_email" : "morecowbell@example.com",
            "request_notes" : "I love oysters!",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("551eb55f555b404d68b88063")
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to Create / Update with the following code, it always overwrites the first element. I can't get it to even

```
var col = db.mongo.collection('game_managers');
// Upsert a game manager record for the game
col.update( {game_id:game.place_id}, {$setOnInsert:{game_id:game.game_id}}, { upsert: true }, function(err, result, upserted) {
    // Append or update game manager record.
    col.update(
        {game_id:game.place_id},
        {$addToSet: {"players":fields}},
        function(err, result) {
            next();
        }
    );
});
```

I modelled the code from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206673/mongodb-upsert-embedded-document) however it doesn't apply to arrays of subdocuments. I do not want to $pull, and then $push a new element, as the subdocument will ultimately have timestamps and some comments[{},{},{}] subdocs on them.

Comment: When you do the first update, _Upsert a game manager record for the game_, do you change the collection's `game_id` to that of `game.game_id`? It seems like it's not doing anything as you would need to use the `$set` operator with the first update.

Comment: You are right it is not doing anything, that is just the initial value. I changed the code to use $setOnInsert: